# Using travis-ci.org with a pure as3 project

Tags: actionscript-3, travis-ci, flexunit

Does anyone know if it is possible to use travis-ci.org for a pure-as3 project (using FlexUnit) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to test my code (unit-test) through an hosted CI platform. This is what travis-ci.org is supposed to do. Unfortunately, they do not mention the support of the AS3 (Flash App). I would like to know if someone has found a workaround to achieve it.

Comment: Sounds to me like SO is the wrong place to ask... Tried the mailing list? https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/travis-ci

Comment: I've worked on projects that we had built with a CI server using FlexUnit testing as well.  We used Maven to define the build process including profiles for running tests that the CI server ran whenever it saw changes on our SVN ( we used Crucible from Atlassian ).  As @weltraumpirat says though you'll need to get a better understanding of what "travis-ci" offers (will it run maven?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have built in support for ActionScript, but if it's possible to run on Ubuntu, then it should be possible to test on Travis.

You can install any dependencies as part of the build process with `apt-get`:

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get -qq update
  - sudo apt-get -qq install some-package another-package
```

Looking at the [FlexUnit docs](http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Continuous_Integration_Support#Linux), it looks like you need a frame buffer available. You may have some luck using xvfb. We have [some docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/) on that, although aimed towards browsers, it may work for you too.

Comment: Thanks ! (sorry for delay)

Comment: Sadly, Flash and testing Flash on a Unix box has been broken from ~2010 to presant.  There are some headless issues with the old Linux Flash player, and later sound card issues and finally 3d issues.  OSX is the typical work-around for testing Flash in a unix like environment.

Answer (score 2):

This GitHub [Travis-CI ActionScript Demo](https://github.com/Larusso/travis-CI-actionscript-demo) project is a great starting place to get up and running with UnitTesting a Flash project with Travis-CI.

Much like in FlashBuilder the UnitTest suites and libraries are utilizing Flex; however, your project can be 'pure-as3' project.  The demo utilizes OSX Travis worker.  The Flash Player will be downloaded from the Adobe website at runtime. All build dependencies (flex sdk, flex unit) will be resolved by [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) with [flex-mojos](http://code.google.com/p/flex-mojos/)

Many of the Flex-Mojos resources are drying up; however, if you are utilizing the Apache-FlexSDK's you'll want to look [here for the latest version](https://flexmojos.atlassian.net/wiki/display/FLEXMOJOS/Home)).